# return user-defined data structure from graphene (graphql) mutation

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I have a mutation where I would like to return arbitrarily shaped data, but I'm having a hard time envisioning how to do this via a [graphene](https://graphene-python.org/) mutation.

I would like to return data like this:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "success": [
            {
                "id": "abc123",
                "goober": {
                    "success": [
                        {
                            "id": "goober-type-1",
                            "baz": "blahblahblah"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "goober-type-2",
                            "baz": "blahblahblah"
                        }
                    ],
                    "failed": [],
                    "cancelled": []
                },
                "tronic": {
                    "success": [
                        {
                            "id": "tronic-type-1",
                            "baz": "blahblahblah"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "tronic-type-2",
                            "baz": "blahblahblah"
                        }
                    ],
                    "failed": [],
                    "cancelled": []
                }
            }
        ],
        "failed": [
            {
                "id": "abc123",
                "goober": {
                    "success": [],
                    "failed": [
                        {
                            "id": "goober-type-3",
                            "baz": "blahblahblah"
                        }
                    ],
                    "cancelled": [
                        {
                            "id": "goober-type-4",
                            "baz": "blahblahblah"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "tronic": {
                    "success": [],
                    "failed": [
                        {
                            "id": "tronic-type-4",
                            "baz": "blahblahblah"
                        }
                    ],
                    "cancelled": [
                        {
                            "id": "tronic-type-3",
                            "baz": "blahblahblah"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My instinct was wanting to define `graphene.ObjectType`'s in a fashion like this:

```
class Goober(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.String()
    baz = graphene.String()

class Tronic(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.String()
    baz = graphene.String()

class Foo(graphene.ObjectType):

    id = graphene.String()
    goober = graphene.ObjectType(
        success = graphene.List(Goober),
        failed = graphene.List(Goober),
        cancelled = graphene.List(Goober)
    )
    tronic = graphene.ObjectType(
        success = graphene.List(Tronic),
        failed = graphene.List(Tronic),
        cancelled = graphene.List(Tronic)
    )

class Results(graphene.ObjectType):
    foo = graphene.ObjectType(
        success=graphene.List(Foo),
        failed=graphene.List(Foo)
    )
```

But I'm really not getting anywhere with this approach, and feeling like I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something.

I've had success in other areas, returning SQL objects and some custom ones, but not with generating and returning relatively complex, nested data like this.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truth is that Graphene documentation lacks a lot. Take a look at this rather lengthy but complete example replicating your data:

```
import json
import graphene

# let's just prepare some data
SUCCESS = [{
    "id": "abc123",
    "goober": {
        "success": [
            {
                "id": "goober-type-1",
                "baz": "blahblahblah"
            },
            {
                "id": "goober-type-2",
                "baz": "blahblahblah"
            }
        ],
        "failed": [],
        "cancelled": []
    },
    "tronic": {
        "success": [
            {
                "id": "tronic-type-1",
                "baz": "blahblahblah"
            },
            {
                "id": "tronic-type-2",
                "baz": "blahblahblah"
            }
        ],
        "failed": [],
        "cancelled": []
    }
}]

FAILED = [{
    "id": "abc123",
    "goober": {
        "success": [],
        "failed": [
            {
                "id": "goober-type-3",
                "baz": "blahblahblah"
            }
        ],
        "cancelled": [
            {
                "id": "goober-type-4",
                "baz": "blahblahblah"
            }
        ]
    },
    "tronic": {
        "success": [],
        "failed": [
            {
                "id": "tronic-type-4",
                "baz": "blahblahblah"
            }
        ],
        "cancelled": [
            {
                "id": "tronic-type-3",
                "baz": "blahblahblah"
            }
        ]
    }
}]

class Goober(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.String()
    baz = graphene.String()

class Tronic(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.String()
    baz = graphene.String()

class GooberResult(graphene.ObjectType):
    success = graphene.List(Goober)
    failed = graphene.List(Goober)
    cancelled = graphene.List(Goober)

class TronicResult(graphene.ObjectType):
    success = graphene.List(Tronic)
    failed = graphene.List(Tronic)
    cancelled = graphene.List(Tronic)

class FooResult(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.String()
    goober = graphene.Field(GooberResult)
    tronic = graphene.Field(TronicResult)

class Foo(graphene.Mutation):
    success = graphene.List(FooResult)
    failed = graphene.List(FooResult)

    def mutate(self, info):
        # provide some data as a mutation result
        success = SUCCESS
        failed = FAILED
        return Foo(success=success, failed=failed)

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    foo = Foo.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(mutation=Mutation)
result = schema.execute("""
mutation Foo {
    foo {
        success {
            id
            goober {
                success {
                    id
                    baz
                }
            }
        }
        failed {
            id
            tronic {
                cancelled {
                    id
                    baz
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
""")

print(json.dumps(result.data, indent=2))
```

When you run this script, you'll get the expected result:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "success": [
      {
        "id": "abc123",
        "goober": {
          "success": [
            {
              "id": "goober-type-1",
              "baz": "blahblahblah"
            },
            {
              "id": "goober-type-2",
              "baz": "blahblahblah"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "failed": [
      {
        "id": "abc123",
        "tronic": {
          "cancelled": [
            {
              "id": "tronic-type-3",
              "baz": "blahblahblah"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The place to start in the documentation is probably at the [relationship between `ObjectType`s and `Field`s](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/objecttypes/#objecttype). [Scalars act as `Field`s](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/scalars/#mounting-scalars), however your defined `ObjectType`s do not, that's why you need to wrap them in `graphene.Field`. Then just take a look at [`Mutation`s](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/mutations/#mutations) to use it all together.

Comment: This is supremely helpful - feel like I'd tried a handful of combinations that danced around that, but not _quite_ that.  Much appreciated!